# Piping results of a command into another command

Tags: arrays, powershell, guid

I'm trying to output the results of a powershell command (Nameley GUID's of tenants) and then display results based on that.

At the moment I have the following code.

```
function get-tenantusers{

begin {
$pten=@()
$pten=Get-MsolPartnerContract -All | Select-Object TenantId
        $pten }
process {
    write-host "processstart"
    foreach ($d in $pten){
        get-Msoluser -TenantId $d
    }

        }
end { write-host "end"}
}
```

When I run the function I get the output:

> Get-MsolUser : Cannot bind parameter 'TenantId'. Cannot convert value "@{TenantId=000000-9e1c-0000-8305-000005c230db}" to type "System.Nullable`1[System.Guid]". Error: "Cannot process
> argument because the value of argument "obj" is null. Change the value of argument "obj" to a non-null value."

Now Im pretty sure that this is because the GUID is a string.  I've tried converting this to  a GUID by using:

```
[guid]d$
```

Still to no avail.

I may be over complicating this.  The reason I want the script is not just for getting usernames but a whole other load of processes in the future from the tenantID.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it at the moment, but at a glance, it looks like you just need to expand the property.

you have `$pten=Get-MsolPartnerContract -All | Select-Object TenantId`

do this instead `$pten=Get-MsolPartnerContract -All | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TenantId`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Select-Object Property` you end up with an object that has that property name. You have two options in this case. First, as [powershellguy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64281482/4085331) pointed out, expand the property to get the value.

```
$pten=Get-MsolPartnerContract -All | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TenantId
```

That would put the actual value(s) in your $d variable in the loop. The other option is to just reference the value by property name again.

```
function get-tenantusers{

begin {
$pten=@()
$pten=Get-MsolPartnerContract -All | Select-Object TenantId
        $pten }
process {
    write-host "processstart"
    foreach ($d in $pten){
        get-Msoluser -TenantId $d.TenantId
    }

        }
end { write-host "end"}
}
```